# Скругление границ между блоками

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Помогите реализовать скругление как на картинке:
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Или `css-ом` кучу псевдо-елементов встраивать или же парой строчек `svg`... Я бы выбрал `svg`

Comment: @Air, всего лишь 4 псевдоэлемента))

Comment: Автор вопроса, не забудьте поставить галочку, если вам помог ответ

Answer (score 5):

**Первый вариант:**
 *С помощью псевдоэлементов.*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  margin: 4rem;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
}

.block::before,
.block::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.block::before {
  left: 43px;
}

.block::after {
  right: 43px;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -37.5px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.circle::before,
.circle::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.circle::before {
  left: -5px;
  top: 25px;
}

.circle::after {
  right: -5px;
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

**Второй вариант:**
 *Обошлось почти без псевдоэлементов. Суть такова, нужно создать 3 куба, сделать им закругление по верхним краям, средний блок опустить в самый низ, сделать по высоте меньше, чем остальные и добавить ему псевдоэлемент, в нашем случае это круг.*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 2rem;
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  width: 75px;
  height: 65px;
  border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
}

.middle {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.middle::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -45px;
  left: -1px;
  width: 77px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block middle"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

**Третий вариант:**
*Самый простой вариант - это нарисовать `<path/>` (`SVG`) в любом векторном редакторе.*

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1200 1200" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <path d="m 13,101 c -0,-37 0,-70 0,-72 0,-2 1,-5 4,-8 l 4,-4 67,0 67,0 3,3 c 2,2 3,5 5,15 10,42 35,65 82,76 7,1 10,1 16,1 46,-5 74,-26 88,-62 1,-4 4,-13 5,-18 1,-8 2,-9 5,-12 l 3,-3 66,0 c 50,0 67,0 69,1 1,0 2,2 3,4 1,2 1,5 1,75 l 0,73 H 261 13 Z" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Лучше бы на `svg` реализовал...)))

Comment: @Air, сейчас добавлю ещё один вариант на CSS и SVG =)